Listen to focus event in child component - handler doesn't capture focus event
I'm using Angular 16 - a parent component consumes a child component  - the parent component is as follows
parent.component.html
<app-gotoitem #initialFocusComponent (initialFocusNativeElementFocus)="focusHandler($event)"></app-gotostudent>

parent.component.ts
@ViewChildren('initialFocusComponent') initialFocusComponents: QueryList<any>;
...
focusHandler(e) {
  console.log("do something");
}
...
this.initialFocusComponents.first.setFocus();

In my child component (gotoitem)
child.component.ts
@Output() initialFocusNativeElementFocus = new EventEmitter();
@ViewChild('initialFocus') initialFocus: ElementRef;
...
fromEvent(this.initialFocus.nativeElement, 'focus') //(B)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(elem => {
    this.initialFocusNativeElementFocus.emit(); //(C) <--this doesn't get executed
});
...
public setFocus(): void {
  this.initialFocus.nativeElement.focus(); //(A)
}

However after the child executes the ".focus()" statement (A), the 'focus' event listener (B) doesn't capture the 'focus' event - and hence the 'emit()' (C) is never executed.
I can see the focus event handler attached to the desired HTML element (which this.initialFocus.nativeElement points to, which is a kendo-dropdownlist) - however the focus event listener has two events attached (the first refers to the "document" element [setup via zone.js], the second refers to the element pointed to by this.initialFocus.nativeElement) - see below

If I manually delete the "document" event handler and focus on the element in question the 'focus' handler captures the event and the 'emit()' is executed
How is this scenario normally handled - regardless of whether the "document" event handler is there or not I need the focus event I have defined to also run - or do I need to remove the "document" event handler - if so how ?
Many thanks

as I read this "do something" should be written when you set the focus and then no other events will emit.  Can you describe what you are trying to do in broader terms?  The event will bubble-up.  (I guess what I'm asking is why you are not just using (focus)="focusHandler()" without having to pass the event.)

thanks @browsermator - In broad terms I was wanting the parent component to control what happens when the child component focus event was done - this is because the thing that needs to happen is something at the parent level (i.e. something the child doesn't need to know about)

I resolved the issue by listening to the focusin event rather than the focus event.  The problem was because the focus event doesn't bubble whereas the focusin does

As far as I can see kendo-dropdownlist can not receive focus (and should NOT by its design). Enter in dev-tools console:
setInterval(() => console.log(document.activeElement), 1000);

Then focus desired element and u will see that span element is focused.

thanks @Petr-Averyanov - the kendo-dropdownlist becomes focusable when Keyboard Navigation functionality is exposed - if you take a look at the first example (half way down the page) at telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pager/… and Inspect the "items per page" kendo-dropdownlist, the kendopagerfocusable attribute is present and tabindex="0" is also set - btw I've run the command you mentioned in the console and the activeElement display the kendo-dropdownlist
